# Updating Flow Status From Active to Inactive using Tooling API

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-flow

Is it possible to update flow status from Active to Inactive using tooling API

Used OTP tooling api to update flow

with below body

{“Metadat”: { “Status”: “Inactive”}}

Answer (score 0):

To update the Flow's status through the tooling api you will want to set the Status to `Obsolete`.

see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flow.htm

you can fetch the active version id of the Flow from the FlowDefintion Object

see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flowdefinition.htm

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to set the flow’s status to inactive , Try setting the activeVersionNumber to 0
i.e., ****{“Metadata": {"activeVersionNumber":0}}****.Hope this works for you!